# Hierarchy class Linq search

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use Linq to search for a certain Product.
How would I conduct this?

```
public class ShoppingCart : List<CartLine>
{
    // implement constructors you want available
    public ShoppingCart(){}

    public ShoppingCart( IEnumerable<CartLine> collection ) : base( collection ) {}

    public ShoppingCart( int capacity ) : base( capacity ) {}
}

public class CartLine
{
    public int CartLineId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public string ImageLocation { get; set; }

    public int? ProductCategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual ProductCategory ProductCategory { get; set; }
}

ShoppingCart shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();
```

**Linq Query Search:**
This keeps giving me errors, trying to use Resharper to get this in my repository pattern, testing

```
 shoppingCart.Find(p=>p.CartLine.Product.ProductName) = "SamsungTV"
```

Comment: Hi! In first, the predicate that is used in linq expression is wrong: it must return a boolean result. I think you want to use `shoppingCart.Find(p=>p.CartLine.Product == "SamsungTV")`. But `Product` property of a `CartLine` instance is not string. See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=netframework-4.7.2) to use the method properly.

Comment: What are you trying to do? search for `Product` with name `"SamsungTV"`?

Comment: you got it I believe,             shoppingCart.Find(p => p.Product.ProductName == "SamsungTV"); Thanks

Comment: This is not linq. The `Find` method belongs to the `List<T>` class. Also, you should read [Eric Lippert's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21694054/3094533) to Why not inherit from List<T>? And another thing - you can simply use a `Dictionary<Product, int>` to store the cart, where the `int` stands for quantity, and remove the `CartLine` class.

Comment: so many good suggestions, I was reading from here, he has Cartlineid, but thanks for the input https://github.com/Apress/pro-asp.net-core-mvc-2/blob/master/10%20-%20SportsStore%20-%20Cart/SportsStore/SportsStore/Models/Cart.cs

Comment: @ZoharPeled, oh, yes, you are right! It's all in a hurry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `shoppingCart.Find(p=>p.CartLine.Product.ProductName)`, `p` is already a `CartLine`. You also need to compare `ProductName` inside the query. Try

```
CartLine cartLine = shoppingCart.Find(p => p.Product.ProductName == "SamsungTV");
```

Answer (score 1):

For LINQ can u use a "where" :

```
var result =  shoppingCart.Product.Where(x => x.ProductName == "SamsungTV").ToList();
```

now you will have as a list of all in "Result" only where product name is Samsung TV ,to do what you like with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find instance of `CartLine` that' product name is `"SamsungTV"` you could use the following expression:

```
CartLine cartLine = shoppingCart.Find(p => String.Equals(p.Product?.ProductName, "SamsungTV", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

It will find product using ordinal (binary) sort rules and ignoring the case of product name. If you want to use another string comparison rules, define it using [`StringComparison`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=netframework-4.7.2) enumeration.